# Assertions on ApplicationEvents in Spring Boot Test using @RecordApplicationEvents fail unexpectedly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I am writing some improvements in my code that use classes inheriting an ApplicationEvent (e.g. `UserSubscribedEvent`). In my test I want to validate that the `@Service` did execute the expected logic (c.q. subscription handling; push of the event for further handling). In my test method I do not see the assertion succeed that I expect to succeed.

The test class is annotated with `@RecordApplicationEvents`. With some log lines I have verified the publisher is called and I see that a listener handled that event. So the code itself works as expected.

```kotlin
@Test
internal fun `validate user subscribed event handling`(applicationEvents: ApplicationEvents) {

assertThat(applicationEvents.stream(UserSubscribedEvent::class.java)).singleElement()
            .satisfies({
                ...
            })
}
```

This assertion fails, it says there are no events of type `UserSubscribedEvents`. However, the assertion is wrong here. I see in my logs that the Listener has received the ApplicationEvent and handled it. So I expect the assertion to succeed.

An observation I did make was that the integration test runs on thread `main` where the event handler works on thread `executor-1`. I am still unsure if that makes a difference.

I am using Spring Test 5.3.25. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.25/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/event/ApplicationEvents.html

Comment: To answer the question "did you follow the guide?", yes. I have followed the documentation and that stated I should work like this. So I expected this to work. As far as I see, there is no transaction being executed in. So that should also not walk in my way. I am a bit blind of what direction to look at now.

Comment: After some more rubber duck programming, and a chat with a colleague we've found the problem laying in the fact that we use a task executor. In the version we use, the `@RecordApplicationEvents` only records events that happen in the current thread. So, I've found the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

After some more rubber duck programming, and a chat with a colleague we've found the problem laying in the fact that we use a task executor. In the version we use, the @RecordApplicationEvents only records events that happen in the current thread. So, I've found the culprit here.

To also answer it properly, I'll do some more testing with the latest Spring Boot 3.x which uses Spring Framework 6.x to see if that solves the issue I was having.

Comment: Spring Framework 6.1 includes additional support for recording events from other threads. For details, see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/30020

Comment: @SamBrannen it does indeed, however it has not been updated inside Spring Boot yet. That seems to come on a 3.1.x release. We've temporarily fixed our issue by using a MockBean of the task executor returning a single threaded task executor. That works for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).